# .vimrc use filename that is currently editing

Tags: vim, gvimrc

I have a plugin for `VIM` which is basically provides an interface for my `SVN` ([vcscommand.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90)). And I've mapped `:VCSUpdate` and `:VCSCommit` commands of vcscommand plugin in my `.vimrc`. Everything is perfect, except one thing:

After you call :VCSCommit you usually write comment like so:

```
:VCSCommit I've made some minor changes to this file
```

In our company's deployment system it is not highlighted which file was commited, so we usually write our comments like so:

```
:VCSCommit I've made some minor changes to file .vimrc
```

In the deployment system we see all this commits, so we can tell which file is to be uploaded to production server after "Sync" button pressed.

So, I wonder how do I map for :VCSCommit so it would add name of the file as a comment. My mapping so far is:

```
map <C-q> :VCSCommit
```

So after Ctrl+Q press, it shows `:VCSCommit` in the bottom bar, but I'd want to see `:VCSCOmmit my_file_name_that_i_m_editing_now`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
map <C-q> :VCSCommit <C-R>%
```

For more, see

```
:help c_CTRL-R
```

**EDIT**

To insert just the file name when `%` contains a path, use this:

```
map <C-q> :VCSCommit <C-R>=expand("%:p:t")<CR>
```

The `:p` expands the preceding file name to include the full path and the `:t` takes the tail of that path. See

```
:help expand()
```

Comment: Helps, but it's a little not what I expected. It inserts the relevant path to file I'm editing from `pwd`, so it inserts `include/somefile.php`. How do I get just a `somefile.php`. I've read the help and tried the alternate filename (`#`)... still not what I want :( If there is no way to insert filename, I'll go with `<C-R>%`

Comment: @Nemoden: No problem. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an fyi, `svn log -v` will show you what files were modified by a commit, so adding the filename in the commit message shouldn't really be necessary..

First without `-v`:

```
% svn log -r2                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | mkomitee | 2011-05-27 08:56:02 -0400 (Fri, 27 May 2011) | 1 line

change
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the same revision with `-v`:

```
% svn log -vr2                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | mkomitee | 2011-05-27 08:56:02 -0400 (Fri, 27 May 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /baz

change
------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
```

Comment: It's not about `svn` (in which I'm experienced and know how to list changes, so your `fyi` does not advance my knowledge), but about `vim` (in which I'm not that experienced and need help), so this asnwer does not correspond to what I'm asking for. @garyjohn already provided a decent answer. I would not want to downvote though.

Comment: Probably it's my bad - I did not tell that in our deployment system we don't see to which files changed were made, but all we see are just comments to those commits. I will probably make some changes to our system in nearest future like a pop-windows displaying all information about a particular commit, but now I don't have enough time for tweaking internal software... so we still need to include filenate into comments. I know - that sucks...

Comment: That's fine. I just question the need to add information to a commit message that's readily available already. My answer would have been better suited as a comment on the question, because it wasn't really an attempt to answer the question asked.

Comment: Yep :) That's why I responded a little harshly. I'm sorry if it sounded so (I realized that after rereading my comments now). I really appreciate the community's help though.